# History of yasnippet fields

Tags: yasnippet

Is it possible to have a history for the value of a yasnippet field? When I expand a second time a snippet like `\begin{${1:environment}}` I would like to get as suggestion the value I've used for `$1` in the last expansion.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution with a pseudo-field in which I save the previous value and jump to the next. It feels ugly and I hope someone can give a better answer.

```lisp
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: Environment
# key: env
# --
\begin{${1:`(or (and (boundp 'last-snippet-environment) last-snippet-environment) "environment")`}}
  $0${2:$$((lambda ()
    (set (make-local-variable 'last-snippet-environment) (yas-field-value 1))
    (yas-next-field)
    ""
  ))}
\end{$1}
```